# Deploying a simple web application to Tomcat using Ant

Tags: tomcat, deployment, ant

I am trying to deploy my simple web application which consists of one web servlet and a JSP. I haven't used any framework such as Spring or anything, just a *helloWorld* web app.

I am using Ant to for deployment purpose. But when I run my deploy target it gives me:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/B2CConverter

I am using Tomcat 7 and I have included all libraries under Tomcat lib directory and  *tomcat-juli.jar* into my `webcontent/web-inf/lib` as well.

My Ant file targets are as follows:

```xml
<!-- Configure the directory into which the web application is built -->
    <property name="build" value="${basedir}/build" />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
    <property name="src.dir" value="${basedir}/src" />

    <!-- Configure the context path for this application -->
    <property name="path" value="/myapp" />

    <!-- Configure properties to access the Manager application -->
    <property name="url" value="http://localhost:8080/manager/text" />
    <property name="username" value="gbids" />
    <property name="password" value="tomcat" />

    <!-- Configure the custom Ant tasks for the Manager application -->
    <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask" />
    <taskdef name="list" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ListTask" />
    <taskdef name="reload" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ReloadTask" />
    <taskdef name="findleaks" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.FindLeaksTask" />
    <taskdef name="resources" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.ResourcesTask" />
    <taskdef name="start" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StartTask" />
    <taskdef name="stop" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.StopTask" />
    <taskdef name="undeploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.UndeployTask" />

<!-- Class path -->
    <path id="project.classpath">
        <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
            <include name="**/*.zip" />
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <!-- Executable Targets -->
    <target name="compile" description="Compile web application">
        <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${build}/classes" nowarn="on">
            <classpath refid="project.classpath" />
        </javac>

    </target>

    <target name="makeWar" depends="compile">
        <delete file="${build}${path}.war"/>
        <war destfile="${build}${path}.war" webxml="WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml">
            <fileset dir="WebContent" />
            <lib dir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" />
            <classes dir="build/classes" />
        </war>
    </target>

    <target name="deploy" description="Install web application" depends="makeWar" >
        <deploy url="${url}" username="${username}" password="${password}" path="${path}" war="${build}${path}.war" />
    </target>
```

And I also have following in my *tomcat-users.xml* file:

```xml
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>

  <user username="manager" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
  <user username="admin" password="tomcat" roles="admin-gui"/>
  <user username="gbids" password="tomcat" roles="manager-script"/>
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: It is not giving me a stack trace. Just an exception in ant console.

deploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Buddhi\workspace-indigo\AntTestDeploy\build.xml:52: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tomcat/util/buf/B2CConverter

Total time: 1 second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be smarter about your `<taskdef>`s:

```
<property name="catalina.home" value="/path/to/tomcat" />
<path id="tomcat.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${catalina.home}" includes="lib/*.jar" />
</path>

.
.
.

<taskdef name="deploy"
         classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask"
         classpathref="tomcat.classpath" />
```

You shouldn't have any of Tomcat's JAR files in your project's `WEB-INF/lib` directory: remove them all.

Finally, getting more information from ant is easy: run `ant --help` to see what debugging options you have.

Comment: I tried this way, It seems it is detecting all jar files within my tomcat's lib directory correctly (because in eclipse it shows me all jar file within that lib directory in a tool tip text when i hover mouse over path id element in ant window) but when i run this, ant says that it still need 'tomcat-juli.jar' and 'tomcat-util.jar' files. (it is working properly when i copy those jar files to ant's lib directory from tomcat's lib directory.)

Comment: 'tomcat-juli.jar' file is not inside tomcat's lib directory, but still it says it cannot find 'tomcat-util.jar' jar file.

Comment: Here is the code.. 
` <property name="catalina.home" value="D:\\Program Files\\apache-tomcat-7.0.34" />

 <path id="tomcat.classpath">
  <fileset dir="${catalina.home}/lib">
   <include name="**/*.jar" />
  </fileset>
 </path>

 <taskdef name="deploy" classname="org.apache.catalina.ant.DeployTask">
  <classpath refid="tomcat.classpath" />
 </taskdef>`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. I was trying to do that task according to the guidelines given in Tomcat documentation. According to that they ask only to copy 'catalina-ant.jar' file to Ant lib directory.

But once I have copied 'tomcat-coyote.jar' , 'tomcat-juli.jar' , 'tomcat-util.jar' files in to the Ant's *lib* directory together with 'catalina-ant.jar' file it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a runtime error. The missing class is part of the "[tomcat-coyote.jar](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3a%22org.apache.tomcat%22%20AND%20fc%3a%22org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.B2CConverter%22)", are you sure it has been copied properly into your war file?

Check the wAR files contents as follows:

```
unzip -t myapp.war | more
```

The jars should all be located under the "WEB-INF/lib" directory. Anywhere else means they're not included on the classpath and would explain this error